# How to reduce snapshot sizes

Tags: elasticsearch

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/backup-repository-size-is-much-bigger-than-indices-size/47469 discusses a problem that snapshots can be too large.

I do not think removing old snapshots is the solution because if the old snapshot has segments that newer snapshots do not have, we are not able to recover the data after removing old snapshots...

Does elasticsearch have a way to identify if any snapshots are safe to remove because latest snapshots 'cover' them? Or does elasticsearch have a way to clean up old backup segments that are covered by the latest segments.

The other solution is periodically generating a new snapshot from scratch... but I am not sure if this is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Does elasticsearch have a way to identify if any snapshots are safe to remove because latest snapshots 'cover' them?

It does, in the very same thread you linked they [talk about it](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/backup-repository-size-is-much-bigger-than-indices-size/47469/7):

> Deleting old snapshots will remove segments that no snapshot longer refer to, and will reduce storage space.

#### How does this work?

Let's suppose you created two snapshots, on 2018-10-04 and 2018-10-05, and you want to delete the one of 2018-10-05. Here is what will happen:

[image: Elasticsearch snapshot removal]

The newer Snapshot 2018-10-05 references some of the segments that Snapshot 2018-10-04 does (the 2 and 3), although it also contains another one, number 4. Once you delete Snapshot 2018-10-04 actually only Segment 1 will be deleted.

#### Will any data get lost?

Strictly speaking, yes. If on the date of the first snapshot, 2018-10-04, your index contained some documents that by the date 2018-10-05 were deleted, then it is likely that they will be lost, because snapshot of the date 2018-10-05 only guarantees you the complete set of documents present on the moment of creation of the snapshot.

If you need to "go back in time" then you probably don't want to delete the old snapshots - and incremental snapshots, actually, are supposed to store such history pretty efficiently.

If you want to learn more about how Snapshot and Restore works, here's a bit old but still good [blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-snapshot-and-restore).

Hope that helps!